# Spivak Calculus ch 10, Differentiation: for $S(x)=x^2$, why is it better to differentiate $S \circ (\sin\circ S)$ rather than $(S \circ\sin) \circ S$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=\sin^2(x^2)$.

This is a triple composition $S \circ \sin \circ S$, where $S(x)=x^2$. Apparently we can write this as either $$(S \circ \sin) \circ S\tag{1}$$ or $$S \circ (\sin \circ S)\tag{2}$$

From Spivak's Calculus, chapter 10 on Differentiation, page 174:

> The derivative of either expression can be found by applying the Chain
> Rule twice; the only doubtful point is whether the two expressions
> lead to equally simple calculations. **As a matter of fact, as any
> experienced differentiator knows, it is much better to use the
> second.**

$$(S \circ \sin)(x)=(\sin(x))^2$$

$$((S \circ \sin) \circ S)(x)=(\sin(x^2))^2$$

$$((S \circ \sin) \circ S)'(x) = (S \circ \sin)'(S(x))\cdot S'(x)=2\sin(x^2)\cos(x^2) \cdot2x\tag{3}$$

$$(\sin \circ S)(x)=\sin(x^2)$$

$$(S \circ (\sin \circ S))(x)=(\sin(x^2))^2$$

$$(S \circ (\sin \circ S))'(x)=S'((\sin \circ S)(x))\cdot (\sin \circ S)'(x)=2\sin(x^2)\cdot \cos(x^2)2x\tag{4}$$

The difference between the differentiations in $(3)$ and $(4)$ is clear: in $(3)$ you first differentiate a function involving a square and a sine, and then you differentiate a square function; in $(4)$ you first differentiate a square function, and then you differentiate a sine and a square function.

In this particular example, both ways seem easy enough. I imagine Spivak's comment about one way being better refers to other more complicated functions. **Why did he say is it much better to use the differentiation as in $(4)$?**

Comment: When using the Chain rule, I find that it is easier to work from the outermost function to the innermost one. That is the first one you write. Note that having obtained the detivative of the outermost square, you proceed to leave that factor alone and work left-to-right to compute the derivative. P.S. use \sin and \cos for the functions. That will typeset them in roman font rather than math italic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider how one might go about differentiating a triple composition that one encounters. Looking at
$$h\Bigl(g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\Bigr)$$
(which is the $S\circ(\sin\circ S)$ analogue) I would first do the derivative of the outermost/first function $h$, evaluate it at the composition $g\circ f$, and then proceed with the derivative of $g\circ f$. And so, if I wanted to do only one derivative at a time, it would look as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} h\Bigl(g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\Bigr) &= h'\Bigl( g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\Bigl(g\bigl( f(x)\Bigr)\Bigr)'\\
&= h'\Bigl( g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\Bigr) g'\bigl( f(x)\bigr) \bigl(f(x)\bigr)'\\
&= h'\Bigl( g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\Bigr) g'\bigl(f(x)\bigr) f'(x).
\end{align*}$$
I have: (i) proceeded left-to-right, outermost-to-innermost function. (ii) Having taken the derivative of my first function, I will no longer deal with that first part of the expression, I will only "unwind" the stuff to the right. And (iii) With some practice, I may be able to do it directly, just writing out that
$$\Bigl( h\bigl(g(f)\bigr)\Bigr)' = h'(g(f))g'(f)f',$$
without having to backtrack. Just: derivative of first function evaluated at next, then derivative of the next function evaluated at the next, etc.

By contrast, let's say that I want to do the chain rule by thinking of the composition as $(h\circ g)\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$; this is the analogue of your $(S\circ \sin)\circ S$ expression. This would mean first doing the following:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(h\circ g)\bigl( f(x)\bigr) = (h\circ g)'(f(x))f'(x)$$
and *then* doing the derivative of $h\circ g$; so that's $h'\circ g$ evaluated at $f(x)$, times $g'$ evaluated at $f(x)$.

Here we are working right-to-left (not how we usually scan a formula or write it), and innermost-to-outermost. It also means doing a bit of a backtrack, and being sure not to get confused when computing $(h\circ g)'(f(x))$ so as not take the derivative of $f(x)$ at some point. More information to keep track of. Whereas in the previous one, we had a kind of "differentiate and forget it" progression, here it appears we don't, as we write it out.

And here we have the functions written as a composition. If we have the functions written out, using for example radicals or exponentiation, then identifying the "innermost function" to perform the chain rule as
$$(\text{bunch of functions})\circ f$$
may not be immediately obvious, while identifying the "outermost function" is usually much easier. For example, to do the derivative of something like
$$\sqrt{(x^3+2)^2 - \sin(x) + \cos^2(x)},$$
doing it from the outside in, as Spivak suggests, means dealing with the square root first, then dealing with the expression $(x^3+2)^2-\sin(x)+\cos^2(x)$, which in turn will have us figure out the derivative of $(x^3+2)^2$, $\sin(x)$, and $(\cos (x))^2$. Trying to do it with "the other way" is much more complicated.

So in general it is much easier to deal with compositions as associated to the right, $h\circ(g\circ (f\circ k))$, because of how we read and write functions, and how this makes us use the Chain Rule sequentially, left-to-right, outermost-to-innermost, and once we've dealt with the function $h$, we won't have to "deal" with it again, we just carry the factor $h'(u)$ around. The other way, we have to work right-to-left, and backtrack, and perhaps have to think hard about how to organize the compositions.